# How do you setup protractor with angular in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs, protractor

I'm having trouble setting up protractor to run with angular with a rails backend. I currently use rake:jasmine to run unit tests but would like to incorporate e2e testing.

What would be the simplest way to get it up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that easy and fast guide

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/practical-protractor.html

I hope it helps

Comment: This guide is not Rails specific.

Answer (score 6):

This gem is pretty straightforward to start testing an angular-rails app
https://github.com/tyronewilson/protractor-rails