# Error installing Protractor in ROR4 + AngularJS app various attempts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, protractor

Using Ubuntu debian flavour, have been unsuccessfully trying to install protractor following:

1. the AngularJS official docs [tutorial](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial)
2. by installing nodejs, npm and then downloading protractor from github repo as suggested [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md).
3. finally by installing the protractor-rails gem as per [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892847/how-do-you-setup-protractor-with-angular-in-a-rails-app).

I can see my nodejs version being: v0.10.25 and npm version being 1.3.10

however when I run either npm install protractor, or npm install -g protractor or follow the steps as per [Protractor::Rails](https://github.com/tyronewilson/protractor-rails)

in **all cases** I get the same error:

[image]

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Try `sudo rake protractor:install`

Comment: @RAJ done it already: sudo: rake: command not found :-(

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is a problem of permissions for creating directory.

You should try to set the permission on npm directory in your home dir.

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

Comment: it is indeed an issue with permission + some debian legacy code as described in my answer. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a permissions issue coupled with some linux legacy code.

For those who may run into the same issue, a few steps to follow to sort this out:

- the Debian installation has a legacy dir called node, this dir has to be removed and the package nodejs-legacy be installed instead.
- Once nodejs-legacy has been installed, you may run the protractor installation (in your project folder) as follows:
- sudo npm install -g protractor

once installation is finished check your

> protractor --version

you should then get a Version 2.0.0 (as of today in my case)

You should be ready to update your webdriver and fire it up.